# Which tags can we use for questions of culinary nomenclature?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I've seen a couple questions lately that deal with nomenclature (how we name something) for foods and techniques: 
For example:

- [What is the English Name for Chitrah Rajmah?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15871/what-is-the-english-name-for-chitra-rajmah)
- [What is this French cuisine technique called, where “a piece of pheasant meat is cooked between two slices of veal, which are then discarded?”](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15709/what-is-this-french-cuisine-technique-called-where-a-piece-of-pheasant-meat-is)
- [Which kind of cream do I use for creme brulee?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/15854/which-kind-of-cream-do-i-use-for-creme-brulee/15855#15855)

There doesn't appear to be a tag that really fits these classes of questions, which deal with "what is this called?"  The "language" tag seems overly broad for this, but "nomenclature" is likely to be a very unfriendly & unfamiliar word for some of the audience.  I've tentatively used "food-names" for the first question, but I'm throwing the floor open.

**What are are good tags for these kinds of questions?**

Answer (score 2):

This is precisely what the [language](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) tag is for.  With 28 questions, it's definitely not overly broad, at least not at this point.

Examples of questions already in this tag:

- What is macaroni cooked in milk called?
- Cookies called monte cows?
- What are “hog lumps”?
- Is there a difference between Stew and Casserole?

I don't see what a "language" tag could be about, other than vocabulary.  If you have or see a question about naming or translation, please, use the [language](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) tag.

I agree that a name such as [vocabulary] or [nomenclature] would be more "correct", but I don't think that [language] is ambiguous or misleading, and it is far more discoverable.  We can add synonyms for the other tags if necessary, they all seem to mean the same thing.

Comment: Okay, I'll roll with that.